Calculate overlapping time periods in PowerQuery
I consider myself a relative newbie to PowerQuery, particularly in terms of my skill level rather than the length of time I've been exposed to it. Recently, I bravely decided to tackle a question on Stack Overflow titled Excel cost calculations using rank function.
My approach was to identify the overlapping periods, count how many there are, and then calculate the final answer. I'm confident that my M code and logic can be significantly improved, and I would love to receive suggestions on how to enhance it. This is especially important to me as I'm trying to implement a very similar solution at work, so I want to ensure it is as efficient and effective as possible.
I appreciate all comments and suggestions.
let
// Load data from the current workbook
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],


// Unpivot columns
UnpivotedColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"App", "Cost"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

// Function to create a list of values less than or equal to the given value for the given app
CreateLessThanList = (app as number, value as number, table as table) =>
    let
        FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(table, each [App] = app and [Value] <= value),
        ValueList = List.Sort(FilteredTable[Value])
    in
        ValueList,

// Add a column with the list of values less than or equal to each value
AddLessThanList = Table.AddColumn(UnpivotedColumns, "LessThanList", each CreateLessThanList([App], [Value], UnpivotedColumns)),

// Expand the list column
ExpandedLessThanList = Table.ExpandListColumn(AddLessThanList, "LessThanList"),

// Sort the rows
SortedRows = Table.Sort(ExpandedLessThanList, {
    {"App", Order.Ascending},
    {"Attribute", Order.Ascending},
    {"LessThanList", Order.Descending}
}),

// Add index columns
AddedIndex0 = Table.AddIndexColumn(SortedRows, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
AddedIndex1 = Table.AddIndexColumn(SortedRows, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

// Merge queries to compare the current and previous rows
MergedQueries = Table.NestedJoin(
    AddedIndex0,
    {"App", "Attribute", "Index"},
    AddedIndex1,
    {"App", "Attribute", "Index"},
    "PreviousRow",
    JoinKind.LeftOuter
),

// Expand the merged table
ExpandedPreviousRow = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergedQueries, "PreviousRow", {"LessThanList"}, {"PreviousLessThanList"}),

// Calculate the custom column
AddedCustom = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedPreviousRow, "Custom", each if [PreviousLessThanList] is null then [LessThanList] else [LessThanList] - [PreviousLessThanList]),

// Remove duplicates and unnecessary columns
RemovedDuplicates = Table.Distinct(AddedCustom, {"App", "Attribute", "Value", "LessThanList"}),
RemovedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(RemovedDuplicates, {"Index", "PreviousLessThanList"}),

// Add adjusted values column
AddedAdjusted = Table.AddColumn(RemovedColumns, "Adjusted", each if [Custom] = 0 then [LessThanList] else [Custom]),
CleanedColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddedAdjusted, {"Custom"}),

// Add a column to count occurrences of each LessThanList value
AddCustomColumn = Table.AddColumn(CleanedColumns, "Count", each List.Count(
    Table.Column(
        Table.SelectRows(CleanedColumns, (row) => row[App] = _[App] and row[LessThanList] = _[LessThanList]), 
        "App"
    )
)),

// Calculate user cost
AddedUserCost = Table.AddColumn(AddCustomColumn, "User cost", each (if [Adjusted] = 0 then [LessThanList] else [Adjusted]) / [Count] * [Cost]),

// Remove unnecessary columns
FinalColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddedUserCost, {"LessThanList", "Adjusted", "Count"}),

// Group rows by App and Attribute, summing the User cost
GroupedRows = Table.Group(FinalColumns, {"App", "Attribute"}, {{"User cost", each List.Sum([User cost]), type number}})
in
GroupedRows

